# SwiftUI transition effect not changed immediately on state change

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, transition

I have a `@State usingOpacity` to control the type of transition on the rectangular and bind it to a Toggle.

When I toggle usingOpacity, the view's transition style does not as my expect.Below is my code and a gif image.

When I toggle to .opacity, the view transition is slide.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct BuggyTransition: View {
  @State var usingOpacity = false
  @State var showSquare = true

  var transitionType: AnyTransition { usingOpacity ? .opacity : .slide }

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 16) {
      Text("Current: \(usingOpacity ? "Opacity" : "Slide")").font(.title)
      Toggle("Using Opacity", isOn: $usingOpacity)
      Button(showSquare ? "Hide the Square" : "Show the Square") {
        withAnimation { showSquare.toggle() }
      }
      .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

      if showSquare {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
          .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
          .foregroundColor(.red)
          .transition(transitionType)
      }
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
  }
}

struct Buggy_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    BuggyTransition()
  }
}
```

I guess that it might be a type issue, but the states involved are basic bool types, and I'm not sure how to get the transition to synchronize with the state of usingOpacity

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Hi, sorry for the confusion in the previous version question, I've update the code and the screen recording gif.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.id()` modifier for `RoundedRectangle()`.

Code example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct BuggyTransition: View {
  @State var usingOpacity = false
  @State var showSquare = true

  var transitionType: AnyTransition { usingOpacity ? .opacity : .slide }

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 16) {
      Text("Current: \(usingOpacity ? "Opacity" : "Slide")").font(.title)
      Toggle("Using Opacity", isOn: $usingOpacity)
      Button(showSquare ? "Hide the Square" : "Show the Square") {
        withAnimation { showSquare.toggle() }
      }
      .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

      if showSquare {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
          .id(UUID()) // Here
          .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
          .foregroundColor(.red)
          .transition(transitionType)
      }
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
  }
}

struct Buggy_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    BuggyTransition()
  }
}
```

More information about `.id()` modifier [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/roundedrectangle/id(_:)).

Comment: That wouldn’t help. The issue is that it seems like old transition is stored for “old” view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77663398/iterating-type-of-assymetric-transition-causes-glitch